# Не удалось открыть файл: File is directory: /home/bitrix/www/

Tags: битрикс

**Пытаюсь развернуть бэкап Битрикса.**

Залил remote.php и сам бэкап в /home/bitrix/www.

**Сразу при распаковке возникает ошибка:**
Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 268435456 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 65 bytes) in /home/bitrix/www/restore.php on line 2867

Увеличил память на 1024, север перезапустил и т.д. Но ошибка остается...

Если после появления данной ошибки в адресной строке нажать Enter, то возникает следующая ошибка:

Не удалось открыть файл: File is directory: /home/bitrix/www/

Задал www права (+дочерние): 7775... Но ошибка Fatal Error... остается и бэкап не разворачивается.

Подскажите пожалуйста из-за чего может возникнуть такая проблема?

Comment: скрипт restore.php используете последней версии?

Comment: restore.php использовал родной. Проблема решилась, оказалось что проблема в https, если коротко, то проблема была на стороне сервера.